# Countability of sequences of zeros and ones that are eventually all ones

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ denote the set of all sequences of zeros and ones that are eventually all ones. Meaning an example sequence is $A_n=\{0,1,1,0,1,0,...,1,1,1,1\}$. How can I show that $A$ is countable?

Comment: Show that $A$ has the same cardinality as the collection of finite sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable.  You should first prove that

$$A_k:=\{ a\in A \; | \; a_n = 1 \;\forall n\geq k\}$$

is countable. Then describe $A$ using the collection $A_k$.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I prove Ak is countable?

Comment: In fact, each $A_k$ is finite! If $a \in A_k$ then you only have to think about the first $k-1$ terms, since you know for sure that all of the latter terms are $1$.  But if I have to put either a $0$ or a $1$ into $k-1$ places, there should be $2^{k-1}$ ways to do it, so you can argue that $|A_k| = 2^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Map the sub sequence that precedes the last zero to the corresponding binary number, i.e. An = {0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,...} -> 01101 == a (=13)
2. Raise 2 to the power of a. b==2^a
3. c=3^{number_of_initial_zeros}
4. if the number of the ones at the end is finite, then d=5^{number_of_ones_at_the_end}, else d=7

The Map An->b*c*d is injective. Any natural number that can be written as a product of powers of 2,3,5,7 is uniquely mapped to an element of A and there is only one way of representing a natural number as a product of powers of prime numbers. Therefore A is countable.